# Why would mirror Jadzia be joined to Dax?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, mirror-universe

In "Through the Looking Glass" (S3E19 of DS9), mirror O'Brien kidnaps Benjamin Sisko from the primary universe to temporarily replace the dead mirror Sisko who is/was the leader of the Terran rebellion. Upon reaching the rebellion's base in the Badlands, we meet mirror Jadzia for the first time. Later, in a meeting of the rebels, Sisko refers to her as Dax, which doesn't surprise or confuse anyone - but why would she be joined with the Dax symbiont?

We know that once joined, the name of the symbiont replaces the family name of the host (as Ezri Tigan becomes Ezri Dax when she is joined to Dax after Jadzia is killed). Therefore Jadzia would only become Jadzia Dax after having joined with Dax, so if she isn't joined she should still be using her original name.

In talking with Sisko, she makes clear that she was a slave on Terok Nor, so she's unlikely to have had the opportunity to be joined with Dax - indeed it seems unlikely that the Alliance would permit any Trill to become joined at all if they are all slaves.

Comment: Because events in the mirror universe have a weird way of working out like they do in the prime universe.

Comment: @Valorum except there is no mirror jake sisko.  The fact that everyone existed except him made the whole concept suspect

Comment: You're right, mirror Jadzia should have joined to Xad.

Answer (score 4):

> [...] it seems unlikely that the Alliance would permit any Trill to become joined at all if they are all slaves.

On the contrary.  A joined Trill would become more valuable as a slave, so the Alliance would certainly permit joining.  In fact, it would probably be mandatory.

The same reasoning leads one to conclude that they would want the best possible pairings, which means adopting the same criteria as in the prime universe.  So it isn't as unlikely as it might seem that the Jadzia was joined to Dax on both sides of the looking glass.

Comment: But Jadzia states she was "shovelling ore for the Intendent". If the Alliance were to force Trill to join, the only reason would be to make use of the past knowledge and experiences of the symbiont - what point is there in then wasting that knowledge in ore processing?

Comment: Perhaps that assignment was a punishment.  Or just a whim of the Intendant, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

In David Mack's Mirror Universe books, called [Relaunch Continuity](https://www.goodreads.com/series/134454-star-trek-mirror-universe-relaunch-continuity) on goodreads and collected together on [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Mirror_Universe), any and all sorts of mental abilities are strongly suppressed, to the point of extermination, by the Alliance.

As of [Rise Like Lions](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=utFIzatOmfIC&pg=PT35&lpg=PT35&dq=David%20Mack%20Mirror%20Universe%20Joined%20Trill&source=bl&ots=ww6m0N5DjY&sig=-sC7BrnPpve2pXW8WcoYzOrravk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPsvrbodPdAhUGyKQKHUsnDKAQ6AEwDnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) (2377-2381) the Dax symbiont still resides in Curzon.

> Curzon Dax, who, in addition to being the galaxy's only remaining Trill joined with a symbiont...

While the whole series of books is marked as "non-canon", it is an enjoyable series that is generally consistent with the main series at point it was published. Under this continuity, Sisko would have been wrong to refer to Jadzia as Dax, and we would have to operate under the assumption that she simply dismissed his use of the name as a mistake or an irrelevance.

Comment: I haven't read any of the dedicated mirror universe relaunch books, only those in the general relaunch continuity with mirror universe elements, so hadn't seen any of that. It certainly makes sense Curzon would have Dax, as he must have been joined before he was at Khitomer (in the prime universe) - and the equivalent time frame for then in the mirror universe could easily be while the Terran Empire still existed.